# Is the Extrude ,dissolve and intersect is removed in blender 2.93?I cant find it anywhere

Tags: extrude

[image]

and in blender 2.93:

[image]

like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGs65oOCt0w said the tool,I cant find it in the latest version blender 2.93,is it already removed?

Comment: Is it not the Alt E > Extrude Manifold function?

Comment: oh man,this is it,thanks!but I cant choose this as the right answer as it's comments now,can u replay it again so I can choose as the right answer to help more new to blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's now <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold* (or header menu > *Mesh > Extrude > Extrude Manifold*)

Comment: Thanks man!!!Have a good day